# How to add child nodes to custom asp.net user control derived from System.Web.UI.Control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls

I would like to know how to add some additional child nodes to a custom user control class derived from  System.Web.UI.Control.

For example currently I have a control that contains no child nodes and on the design surface looks like the following.

```
<cust:MyCustomControl id="ctlMyCustomControl" runat="server" attribute1="somevalue" attribute2="somevalue" ></MyCustomControl>
```

What I am looking for is to have the ability to add n number of child nodes to this control from the design surface and then access their values from the code. So adding to the control stated above.

```
<cust:MyCustomControl id="ctlMyCustomControl" runat="server" attribute1="somevalue" attribute2="somevalue" >
  <childnode1>value1</childnode1>
  <childnode2>value2</childnode2>
</MyCustomControl>
```

It is not clear to me how to access the child nodes.

Any insight on how to do this is appreciated.

Comment: I've given an answer that's *nearly* what you're after markup wise - let me know if you *must* have the markup in the format you've shown. I *think* it's do-able and will have a root around for you to see if I've got an answer for it somewhere =)

Comment: @Rob, this is exactly what I was looking for, and actually the extra parent node "Children" is imo better as you can be more explicit about what the children nodes represent.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: no problemo, glad I could help =) (And I agree with you re: the extra parent node)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to be able to [describe asp.net control properties declaratively](http://www.robertwray.co.uk/blog/2008/02/describing-aspnet-control-properties-declaratively.html).

To be able to have the following markup:

```
<Abc:CustomControlUno runat="server" ID="Control1">
    <Children>
        <Abc:Control1Child IntegerProperty="1" StringProperty="Item1" />
        <Abc:Control1Child IntegerProperty="2" StringProperty="Item2" />
    </Children>
</Abc:CustomControlUno>
```

You need the following code:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomControlUno runat=server></{0}:CustomControlUno>")]
public class CustomControlUno : WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    private Control1ChildrenCollection _children;

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Control1ChildrenCollection Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (_children == null)
                _children = new Control1ChildrenCollection();
            return _children;
        }
    }
}

public class Control1ChildrenCollection : List<Control1Child>
{
}

public class Control1Child
{

    public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
    private string StringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to support the given syntax as-is (without having to use the tag prefixes), you could use a ControlBuilder:

```
 //MyControlBuilder 
 public class MyControlBuilder : ControlBuilder
 {
   public override Type GetChildControlType(string tagName, IDictionary attribs)
   { 
     if (tagName.StartsWith("childnode")) return typeof(Control);
     else return base.GetChildControlType(tagName,attribs);
   }

   public override void AppendLiteralString(string s)
   { 
     //ignore literals betwen tags
   }
 }

 //MyCustomControl
 [ParseChildren(false)]
 [ControlBuilder(typeof(MyControlBuilder))]
 public class MyCustomControl : Control
 {
   public string attribute1 {get;set;}
   public string attribute2 {get;set;}

   protected override void AddParsedSubObject(object obj)
   {
     Control ctrl = (Control) obj;
     LiteralControl childNode = ctrl.Controls[0];

     //Add as-is (e.g., literal "value1")
     Controls.Add(childNode);
   }
 }
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilder.aspx